# Purpose of {credentials: 'include'} in fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a very basic question regarding fetch in javascript.
So when I call an API from `site.com` to `other.com`.
Does the fetch send cookies of `site.com` to `site.com` or the cookies of `other.com` are sent to `site.com`?

Comment: [MDN's article on Using Fetch has a section on credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included)

Comment: But it doesn't state cookies of which site are sent to the targeted site.

Comment: Cookies are only valid for the domain for which they are created. You *can't* send cookies created for "site.com" to "other.com".

Comment: You may want to review [how cookies work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) also.